# Loading weather API data into electron App

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, electron

I started a project with my raspberry pi running an electron App where I need to get the actual weather from an open weather API. I am totally new to electron and not that experienced in Javascript. So I am stuck with getting the Data from the weather API into the App. I can request the Data as JSON or XML data. I tried out different ways I thought it might work but they all failed. So could someone tell me how to get API Data into electron in general?

Comment: Welcome to SO, This question is really broad, I encourage you to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask If you can add some code of what you have done people can have a better sense of how to help you, next time try to be more specific.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will try to ask better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to start with API requests is to use [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios).

After setting up the project (you can follow [Getting Started](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md)), follow these steps:

1. Install Axios `npm install --save axios`
2. Create `main.js` in your project's folder.
3. Load `main.js` inside `index.html` somewhere before `</body>`.
4. Put the JavaScript code inside `main.js`

   ```
   const axios = require('axios');

   function fetchData() {
     // you might need the next line, depending on your API provider.
     axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
     axios.post('api.example.com', {/* here you can pass any parameters you want */})
     .then((response) => {
       // Here you can handle the API response
       // Maybe you want to add to your HTML via JavaScript?
       console.log(response);
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       console.error(error);
     });
   }


   // call the function to start executing it when the page loads inside Electron.
   fetchData();
   ```

Comment: Thank you. This is excatly the help that I needed. :)